# Calculating Distribution Median from Cumulative Distribution Function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

I have a density function defined as below:

```
def f(x):
   if 0<=x<=1:
      return 0.5
   elif 1<x<=3:
      return 0.25
   else:
      return 0.0
```

I vectorized the density function:

```
f = np.vectorize(f)
```

Then I have defined the X array

```
X = np.arange(-10,10,0.001)
```

Finally, the CDF:

```
def CDF(x):
   return quad(f, -np.inf,x)
CDF = np.vectorize(CDF)
CDF_calculated,err=CDF(X)
```

Now I want to calculate the

```
median = np.round(X[np.where(CDF_calculated==0.5)][0])
```

Is what I wrote here correct?

Comment: just integrate the function :-) (probably not what you want, but it is answer to your question)

Comment: @ Jan Thank you. I wanted to split it to small parts and then ask. I edited it and asked the main question.

Comment: If the function is known, I would just define the function "manually"

Comment: Is the function `f` known in advance?

Comment: @JanStránský Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function is a priory known, I would use its analytical integral.
For median computation, I would use something like bisection method (as the function is not smooth)

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import bisect

def f(x):
   if 0<=x<=1:
      return 0.5
   elif 1<x<=3:
      return 0.25
   else:
      return 0.0

  
def cdf(x):
    if 0<=x<=1:
        return 0.5*x
    elif 1<x<=3:
        return 0.5 + 0.25*(x-1)
    elif x<0:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return 1


f = np.vectorize(f)
cdf = np.vectorize(cdf)

fbisect = lambda v: cdf(v) - 0.5

median = bisect(fbisect,0,3)
print(median)
```